# Erro ao rodar plataforma Android no Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Ao executar o comando **cordova run android**, da o seguinte erro:

```
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:zipalignDebugUnable to open '/app_cliente/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug-unaligned.apk' as zip archive
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':zipalignDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/zipalign'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 21.26 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /app_cliente/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/app_cliente/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Até agora não encontrei nada sobre esse problema.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Você já tentou dar upgrade no cordova?
sudo npm install -g cordova

Comment: Fiz isso, mas continua com o mesmo erro.